# Word for object in programming that connects to relay

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a word for an object that connects with something? *Connector* is used to describe a specific part in electronics but I need a word describing that the abstract object connects with something. This is an object in programming that allows the programmer to connect to a local proxy relay. I would like to call it a *relay-connector* but am unsure if it is correct to use *connector* in this context.

Comment: There's no such word as "connector"?  ***connector***: con·nect·or/kəˈnektər/ Noun: A thing that links two or more things together: "a pipe connector". A device for keeping two parts of an electric circuit in contact. https://www.google.com/?q=define:connector

Comment: @Kris That's correct, but doesn't fit in my context. My apologies. I've edited my post to describe the context. Thanks anyway

Comment: As WillHunting suggested, maybe you should post the relevant part of your code (using the word 'connector' for now) to see why it is not appropriate to your needs.

Comment: @Kris Never mind, it does fit my context. My apologies again. It felt wrong because I couldn't find an abstract definition of "connector" as in "any object that connects two or more other objects" which I must have missed in your comment because it's definitely there in your comment. All search results I got was in specific context (electronics, etc). Anyway, thanks a lot! I feel so awkward now. I should have asked if "connector" is the right word or not...

Comment: How about *bridge*?

Comment: Or just *client*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Interface" is appropriate here; it can mean both the contract that an object exposes to other objects (*e.g.*, "All of the program's interfaces are documented in the software development kit") and a particular use or instantiation of that contract (*e.g.*, "Because the security credentials had expired, the visualization software could not obtain an interface to the sensors").

Answer (score 0):

Phil has a great answer with "interface" and that is the one you should probably use, but I'll give you another one: a common paradigm in OOP is that of "slots and signals", where objects declare slots that other objects can send signals to. This is useful for adding generic message-passing, often through inheritance.